# Unique query for one record

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I need to turn off the "where" for one entry that I know of. I don’t understand how to do this. To understand the general problem: I need a collection with all the records + a unique one for which the "where" has not been applied. They should be displayed in the usual manner. Perhaps there is a solution to add this entry to the collection after querying sort the new collection?

```
     $reviews = Review::query()
            ->orderBy("id", 'desc')
            ->whereNotNull('published_at')
             //But don't apply whereNotNull ('published_at') to a record with id = ...
            ->get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$reviews = Review::query()
            ->orderBy("id", 'desc')
            ->whereNotNull('published_at')
            ->orWhere('id', $your_id_here)
            ->get()
```

Is it what you are looking for? It will get all records where `published_at` is not `null` or where the `id` is `$your_id_here`.

Comment: But this method does not work if the result of the request is only this record.

Comment: What do you mean? If there is only one record and this record is `$your_id_here`

Comment: Yes, only one record and she is $your_id_here

Comment: It will also work because it will get the records that are either not published OR with the id you provided. Even if there is one one record. If you don't get the expected results, please update your question with what you get, what you expect to get and I'll take a look.

Comment: My bad. Your code is completely working.